# If $\phi(A)$, and $A\vdash B$, does $\phi(B)$ hold?

Tags: logic, substitution

Simple logic question concerning substitution, where $A$ and $B$ are propositions, and $\phi(A)$ is a formula with one or more instances of the propositional variable $A$,

> If $\phi(A)$, and $A\vdash B$, does $\phi(B)$ hold?

This has probably been asked before, but I'm not sure what to search to get an answer.

Obviously, if $\phi(A)$, $A\vdash B$ *and* $B\vdash A$, then it's safe to assert $\phi(B)$, but I'm unsure if $B\vdash A$ is necessary.

My intuition so far is that $A\vdash B$ is insufficient, but I'm unable to come up with a counterexample.

Comment: Isn't $A \longrightarrow C$ a counterexample? Because of contravariance of $\longrightarrow$ in the first argument.

Comment: @StiftungWarentest that seems simple enough but it still isn't clicking for me. Could you break down why $A\to C$ is a counterexample, if you have the time? I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Tell us more.  What are $A$ and $B$?  propositions?  And what is $\phi$? something where you can plug in a proposition?  So, perhaps, $\phi(A) = \neg A$ would be an example?

Comment: @GEdgar that's all correct. I'll make an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly not. Take $\phi(C) = \neg C$. Let $A = \bot$ and $B = \top$. Then $\vdash \phi(A)$, and $A \vdash B$. But $\vdash \phi(B)$ fails.

Comment: That clicked! Thank you. I think I was overlooking the fact that if $A\vdash B$, then $A$ isn't necessarily true.

Comment: The OP doesn't assert $\vdash \phi(A)$, he merely asserts $\phi(A)$.  And he doesn't ask whether $\vdash \phi(B)$ is true, but whether $\phi(B)$ "holds".  I still think the OP needs to explain the question.

Comment: @GEdgar It is meaningless to assert $\phi(A)$. At most, we can assert $\phi(A)$ is true in some particular model. Of course, with my example, $\phi(A)$ is true in all models, while $\phi(B)$ is false in all models, so this distinction is not too relevant.

Comment: @GEdgar I was under the impression that in this context, $\phi(A)$ is shorthand for $\vdash\phi(A)$